# how do I use phpcbf?

Tags: php, coding-standards

When I run civilint in the build kit I get a long report which ends with this line:

`PHPCBF CAN FIX THE 2 MARKED SNIFF VIOLATIONS AUTOMATICALLY`

Well that sounds great! Where is this mythical `phpcbf` and how do I use it?

When I ran it with just the name of the file it really broke things!!

Answer (score 2):

The phpcs/phpcbf standard in use is a modified Drupal standard, so you call the standard of "Drupal":

`phpcbf --standard="Drupal" filename.php`

However, if you ALSO have unmodified copies of the Drupal standard installed, the trick is to make sure that you're calling the correct version of phpcbf.  For instance, I get this:

`mycomputer» which phpcbf
/home/jon/local/civicrm-buildkit/bin/phpcbf`

If your default phpcbf isn't the one installed with `civicrm-buildkit`, make sure to specify the full path to the one that is.

If that doesn't work:
`civilint` is a script.  So you can edit it in a text editor.  In the latest version, line 179 reads:

`xargs $BINDIR/phpcs --standard="$PHPCS_STD" < "$TMP/php.txt"`

Add an "echo" into it like so:

`xargs echo $BINDIR/phpcs --standard="$PHPCS_STD" < "$TMP/php.txt"`

Run civilint again:

`civilint myfile.php`

Instead of outputting the result of `phpcs` it should instead show the command it WOULD have run.  In my case, it's:

`/home/jon/local/civicrm-buildkit/bin/phpcs --standard=/home/jon/local/civicrm-buildkit/vendor/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer/Drupal fastactionlinks.php`

Change `phpcs` to `phpcbf` and run that command:

`/home/jon/local/civicrm-buildkit/bin/phpcbf --standard=/home/jon/local/civicrm-buildkit/vendor/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer/Drupal fastactionlinks.php`

**Note** Don't forget to remove the `echo` when you're done!

Comment: I get "ERROR: the "Drupal" coding standard is not installed. The installed coding standards are PHPCS, Zend, PSR1, PSR2, PEAR, MySource and Squiz" on buildkit vagrant which a civilint which definitely works.

Comment: @JohnFF I edited my answer to give more details.  Hopefully this fixes things for you. If you're still having trouble, please post details!

Comment: Thanks Jon. Why not wrap it up for us? CiviCbf? "Patch Welcome!" as Xavi says...

Comment: To be honest, I don't use it!  My IDE (Netbeans) fixes the vast majority of these issues for me.  I happened to use `phpcbf` once and only once the day before I saw this.  I was curious how it could possibly auto-fix a particular issue.  I don't imagine I'll use it again for Civi.

Answer (score 1):

One use of `phpcbf` is as a way to automatically format (or'beautify' the code you write in your editor (providing your editor supports it).

For example, Atom supports `phpcbf` via the [beautify](https://atom.io/packages/beautify) package.

Buildkit provides a wrapper (or two) around `phpcbf` set up with appropriate defaults. You can find it in the civicrm-buildkit/bin directory. Specifying that your editor use this file will ensure that your code is 'beautified` the CiviWay.

In my case, I set the phpcbf executable to be `/home/michael/src/civicrm-buildkit/bin/phpcbf-civi` in Atom's *Settings > Packages > Atom Beautify > Executables*.

Answer (score 0):

fixing code automatically is hard, and can break things indeed.

I'm assuming you ran this one?

https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Fixing-Errors-Automatically

if you git diff the file you "fixed", what did you see?

Comment: heya Xavier! I ran `phpcs /path/to/file` and it made a huge mess of the file - it looks like it needs to point to a config file but I couldn't figure it out!